# React Native iOS native module pass parameters

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-native-module

I am writing an NPM library that contains iOS & Android native modules. Important is that I need to pass parameters to the native module before startup. This works great for Android:

```kotlin
package ...

import com.facebook.react.bridge.*

class MyNativeModule(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext, parameter: String) {

    override fun getName(): String {
        return "MyModule"
    }

    @ReactMethod
    fun retrieveParameter(promise: Promise) {
        promise.resolve(parameter)
    }

}
```

When turning off autolinking a library user can just create their own RN package and use the following to set the parameter:

```kotlin
class MyAppRNPackage(private val voizeCore: VoizeCore = VoizeCore.getInstance()) : ReactPackage {
    override fun createNativeModules(reactApplicationContext: ReactApplicationContext): List<NativeModule> {
        return arrayListOf<NativeModule>(
            MyNativeModule(reactApplicationContext, "this is the parameter"),
        )
    }

    override fun createViewManagers(reactApplicationContext: ReactApplicationContext): List<ViewManager<*, *>> {
        return emptyList()
    }
}
```

In iOS the native module would look something like this:

```objectivec
// MyNativeModule.m
#import "MyNativeModule.h"

@implementation MyNativeModule

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(retrieveParameter:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter: (RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
    resolve(???)
}

@end
```

But how is it possible to set a parameter for the iOS module? The problem is that in iOS, native modules can not be registered manually. Furthermore, only classes are registered not class instances.

Any idea how you could pass parameters from native code to the iOS native module?